# How can i restrict Wordpress editor from Promoting user to same (editor) level role?

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I am creating a Membership site with WordPress and want to restrict Manager from promoting lower level member to Manager level. In other words I want to allow Manager to promote new users (unapproved) to Member (approved)  level only and want to hide Manager role option from the roles list.

[Please check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7lz5.jpg)

Comment: share your code which you have tried

Comment: i am not using code, i am using ACF plugin for defining custom fields at registration form and PHP snippets for getting user meta and showing users list in html table.

in that table i am giving my client (editor) a link to edit user details (with user-edit.php link)